Customized key combination can't enable JavaScript omnicompletion in <script></script> tags in html?
Set , as <C-X><C-O> to trigger javascriptcomplete in .vimrc:
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
autocmd FileType javascript set omnifunc=javascriptcomplete#CompleteJS
autocmd FileType javascript inoremap  ,   <C-X><C-O>

The omnifunction of javascriptcomplete can trigger by , when editting js file ,then to edit a html file.
  <script>
      document.
  </script>

, can't trigger omnifunction of javascriptcomplete when cursor is at the .,only ctrl+x  ctrl+o can trigger the omnifunction,is that a normal action by default?

Again, the following line is useless as Vim already does it for you:
autocmd FileType javascript set omnifunc=javascriptcomplete#CompleteJS

which reduces your vimrc to:
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
autocmd FileType javascript inoremap , <C-X><C-O>

Now, you are trying to create that custom insert mode mapping for the javascript filetype while trying to use it in a buffer with the html filetype, which doesn't make sense.
This would make more sense:
autocmd FileType javascript,html inoremap , <C-X><C-O>

But it would still be wrong, because that mapping is global, which means that it it will leak to other filetypes, something that you don't want to happen. It should be scoped to the current buffer:
autocmd FileType javascript,html inoremap <buffer> , <C-X><C-O>

See :help :map-buffer.
And, yet again, . and , are far too common to be used to trigger completion. You should use a key sequence that has little chance of appearing in your code or in the content of the HTML.
